# Доступ к приватному репозиторию на Github для других участников

Tags: git, github

У меня есть репозиторий на Github, он приватный. И есть например друг, который хочет его просмотреть, но не редактировать. Как ему предоставить доступ без добавления в команду?

Comment: Сам недавно искал. Видимо никак.

Comment: @holyblackcat, видимо придётся только через добавления в команду...

Comment: Формально, есть токены, которым доступ можно разграничивать. Но, они вроде только для приложений, глазами не посмотреть. Доступ только на чтение можно организовать архивом - скачиваете, перекидываете другу.

Comment: @monk, ну и как токены помогут?

Comment: Для просмотра на самом гитхабе - точно никак. В целом, из простых вариантов - дать доступ через команду, но запретить пуш в мастер например.

Comment: @monk, спасибо. Конечно я ещё тур в Github, но что  значит master?

Comment: Ветка (branch) в которой ведется разработка. У вас может называться иначе, это название по умолчанию.

Comment: Добавь проект на GitLab

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Заходите в [настройки репозитория](https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository), там есть Collaborators - там и добавляйте друга. К приветному репозиторию вы можете добавить до 3 человек.

Но это будет по сути полный доступ к репозиторию. Дать доступ только на чтение, видимо, [нет возможности](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Can-I-give-read-only-access-to-a-private-repo-from-a-developer/m-p/2062#M640).

Answer (score 5):

Заходите в настройки репозитория

1. Settings
2. Repositories
3. Manage access
4. Invite a collaborator
5. Скидывайте ссылку тому, кому дали доступ или приглашения придет на email

Comment: зачем вы написали ответ? я понимаю, вы хотите набить репутацию, но вы понимаете, что вы: 1. по сути дали копию первого ответа, 2. подняли старый вопрос, на который уже есть принятый ответ. Не стоит так делать